# Cloned GitHub repos ask for a password, while originally created don't

Tags: git, github

I've just lost a bunch of repositories from my disk, so I've cloned them from GitHub. These are now asking for username and password each time I push something to GitHub. Those that haven't been deleted don't do that.
The only solution I've read for getting rid of username/password prompt is generating ssh key. The thing is I already have a key, otherwise I couldn't push without prompts in those repos, that I didn't clone.

I've looked at `git config` for two of my repositories, one that I can push without password and one that I've cloned. The only difference was `branch.master.remote` and `branch.master.merge` settings, which I unset, making `git config` the same. But the prompt is still there.

I'm not even sure that generating new ssh key will work. What are my options?

Comment: Please see http://help.github.com/ssh-issues/ and give more details. What happens when you try to SSH?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My guess:

Your old repositories used SSH remotes (`git@github.com:` or `ssh://git@github.com/` prefixes), which used public-key authentication. (In fact, the Github SSH server *never* asks for a password.)

Your new repositories use HTTP remotes (`https://username@github.com/`), which only support password-based *HTTP Basic* authentication and do not use your SSH keys.

Change your remote URLs to use SSH again. Use `git remote set-url` or edit `.git/config` to do this. Replace

```
https://username@github.com/username/repo.git
```

with just

```
git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

---

You can even have an entry in your `~/.gitconfig` that tells git to translate remote URLs from HTTP or Git to SSH.

This way, if your repository is configured for a HTTP or Git remote, git will ignore that setting when pushing and will use SSH instead.

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    pushInsteadOf = git://github.com/
    pushInsteadOf = https://github.com/
```

(An `insteadOf =` setting is also possible, to override both pulling *and* pushing.)